# Throttle hide/show component ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new on react and now I have a problem. I have in my app 3 component:
**App Component:**

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            showToast:false,
            toastMessage: ""
        };

        this.handleShowToast = this.handleShowToast.bind(this);
    };

    handleShowToast(message) {
        this.setState({ showToast: true, toastMessage: message});
        setTimeout(function() { 
            if(this.state.showToast){
                this.setState({ showToast: false });

            }}.bind(this), 2000);
        };


  render() {
    return (
            <div id="cont">
               <Toast showToast={this.state.showToast} messageToast={this.state.toastMessage} />
               <Header handleToast={this.handleShowToast}/>
            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my **Header** components I click on button and **hadleShowToast** is execute and **Toast** Component is correctly show and it work, but I would (now i make with setInterval, but doesn't work, because if I click a second time button it immediately hide because there is a precendent setInterval) hide Toast component, after 2 second, if I don't click again a button, but if I click again button in **Header** component i would reset timer.
How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) to clear timers:

```
handleShowToast(message) {
    this.setState({ showToast: true, toastMessage: message});
    if (this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        if(this.state.showToast){
            this.setState({ showToast: false });
        }
        this.timer = null;
    }.bind(this), 2000);
}
```

Comment: Yes!! thankyou! I will accept! But Can I answer what is debounce function?
I 've tried but it return "undefined "_" "

Comment: I am guessing this is [lodash.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). To use that you will need to include lodash (or underscore) library.